# How to implement postgres full-text with joins across multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `brands` table and a `products` table with schema like below:

```
brands (
    brandId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
);

products (
    productId SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    product_desc TEXT,
    brandId BIGINT REFERENCES brands(brandId)
);
```

I have a naive search implementation here which somewhat works, but is not that great at search.

```
SELECT productid, products.brandid, products.title FROM brands 
JOIN products ON products.brandid = brands.brandid
WHERE LOWER(brands.slug) LIKE LOWER('%_search_query_here%')
OR LOWER(brands.name) LIKE LOWER('%_search_query_here%')
OR LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('_search_query_here')
OR LOWER(product_desc) LIKE LOWER('_search_query_here');
```

I have tried to implement full-text search in Postgres but I am unsure as to how to include results searching across multiple tables, like below. I'm trying to take a user's `searchQuery` and return any products that have `searcQuery` in the product's description, title, or if `searchQuery` mentions a particular brand, and then in this case, return products from that brand.

I tried this and know I must use tsvectors, but not quite there yet.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW search2
AS
SELECT b.brandid, to_tsvector(concat_ws(' ',p.productid, p.brandid, p.title, p.product_desc)) AS tsv
FROM brands AS b
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.brandid = b.brandid;

SELECT * FROM search2 WHERE tsv @@ plainto_tsquery('oogle');
```

I am asking if there are any suggestions for joining across tables for a full-text search query?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> to_tsvector(concat_ws(' ',p.productid, p.brandid, p.title, p.product_desc)) AS tsv
> ```

The four columns listed here are not the four columns you appear to want to search on, from your other example.  Also, since all four of these ones are from the same table, there is no point in doing it in a materialized view rather than in the original table.  Isn't the whole point of using a materialized view to allow one index to be over something derived from columns from different tables?

Rather than doing a materialized view, you could instead run two queries and combine them with UNION or UNION ALL.

```
SELECT productid, products.brandid, products.title 
FROM brands JOIN products ON products.brandid = brands.brandid
WHERE something_on_brands_columns
UNION
SELECT productid, products.brandid, products.title 
FROM brands JOIN products ON products.brandid = brands.brandid
WHERE something_on_products_columns
```

Comment: i am just getting started to materialized views, i guess i do need them since i need to join across columns from different tables. my data points across two different tables.

Comment: @KimLee  Your example doesn't **show** it being across different tables, though.

Comment: yeah my example is wrong then. i need to take more time to figure out how to do this as i am searching across parameters from two tables.